# Spring security authenticate exceptions handling

Tags: authentication, exception, spring-security

I have an app using Spring Security 3.0.x. There I have a custom `AuthenticationProvider`:

```java
public class AppAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        ...
        if (!check1()) throw new UsernameNotFoundException();
        if (!check2()) throw new DisabledException();
        ...
    }
```

I'd like to send custom response codes on each exception, for example 404 for UsernameNotFoundException, 403 for DisabledException etc. For now, I just have authentication-failure-url in my spring security configuration so I get redirect to it on each exception in authenticate().

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Authentication failure handler :

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
  super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
  if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UsernameNotFoundException.class)) {
    showMessage("BAD_CREDENTIAL");
  } else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(DisabledException.class)) {
    showMessage("USER_DISABLED");
  }
}
```

configuration :

```xml
<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
      class="com.apackage.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/index.jsp"/>
</bean>
<security:http auto-config="true">
  <security:form-login default-target-url="/welcome.jsp" authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: I didn't find a showMessage() method in SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler class (I am using Spring Security version 3.1.x). Do you know which version you were using?

Comment: Sorry, the showMessage method is specific to my implementation and do not come from spring.  The original code was too much to show.

Comment: @baraber how to pass exception type to the controller method ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow The controller method ?  There is no controller in my example, I'm sorry I do not understand the question :(

Answer (score 15):

It's usually a bad idea to provide details on why an authentication failed as it can provide an attacker with useful information. For example, it can allow them to probe for valid account names.

If you need to customize things, then rather than using an `authentication-failure-url`, you can use `authentication-failure-handler-ref` to inject a custom [`AuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-flow-handling) bean where you can implement different behaviour depending on the exception.

Comment: how to pass information from AuthenticationFailureHandler to controller method ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the below tags for your customize authentication in jsp page.

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope[\"SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION\"].message eq 'Bad credentials'}">
Username/Password entered is incorrect.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${sessionScope[\"SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION\"].message eq 'User is disabled'}">
Your account is disabled, please contact administrator.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(sessionScope[\"SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION\"].message,'A communications error has been detected')}">
Database connection is down, try after sometime.
</c:if>
```

Also include the below tag library for properly working

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec"%>
```

...