# How to handle "Could not get JDBC Connection exception" in Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, jdbc

I am implementing Spring Security Authentication and Authorization for the first time.

When Spring Security does authentication with JDBC-USER-SERVICE by executing the following query

`select username, password, status as enabled from bbp_user where username=?`

I am getting the following **exception**

```
2014-12-08 21:23:23,852 [http-bio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  - 
Authentication request failed: 
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: **Could not get JDBC 
Connection**; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: **The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
```

Please find the part of security XML

```
<form-login 
        login-page="/inventory/auth/login" 
        default-target-url="/inventory/landing/loadDashBoardPage"
        authentication-failure-url="/inventory/auth/login?error"
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, status as enabled from bbp_user where username=?"
            />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Upon authentication failure with username and password, I have designed to re-post the login page with error message like "invalid username or password".

But, **How to redirect JDBC kind of underlying exception to the specific error page as mentioned in the web.xml**

```
<!-- Application Exceptions -->
<error-page>
    <!-- Route all exceptions to error page -->
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/Dashboard/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I am using Spring 3.0.5 and Spring Security version 3.1.0, fyi.

Please advise.  Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using ?

Comment: Spring 3.0.5 and Spring Security 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways doing this. The traditional way of doing it is in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code> <!-- All Internal Server Errors -->
    <location>/error.htm</location>
</error-page>
```

Now define a Controller with `@RequestMapping("/error")` similar to this:

```
 @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handle500()
    {
      return "internalServer";
    }
```

Have a view defined for `internalServer`.

The other way would be doing it in Spring security configurations. The `authentication-failure-url` attribute. This means that any exception during the login process will take you the URL defined in this attribute. Then define a view corresponding to the URL specified in the `authentication-failure-url`

You are on a little older version of Spring. From Spring v3.2 there is something called as `@ControllerAdvice` which simplifies the Exception handling in MVC.

Comment: Presently, in my security xml file, I have included authentication-failure-url. It is working. Authentication failures such as "user name not found", "password is wrong" should goto URL mentioned in the authentication-failure-url attribute.  But for unexpected underlying exception such as "Could not establish JDBC connection" during authentication, I would like to redirect to the page I mentioned in <error-page> from web.xml.  But it is not happening now. Presently, for any exception during authentication, spring security redirects it to the page which I defined in authentication-failure-url.

Comment: I understand as per your advise, we can write a Controller to handle.  How spring security differentiates between the exception and redirects it the pages accordingly? Kindly advise.

Comment: Spring security does not do it. When there is an exception, in your web.xml, as defined, you will be redirected to the /error.htm. This request will be handled by one of your defined Controllers annotated with @RequestMapping("/error"). From this controller, Its upto you to redirect the request to an error page. See the first part of the answer

Comment: I am looking at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731144/spring-security-authenticate-exceptions-handling

Comment: In the above link, they handling UsernameNotFoundException, DisabledException specifically.  Likewise, can't we have one more if-condition to match with org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException which I get in log and re-direct it to the error page defined in the web.xml??

Comment: First, my heartful thanks for your time on disuccsing this issue.  I am just wondering whether we could implement Custom authentication provider to help spring security to redirect to the pages based on the exception.

Comment: Remember, all these exception end up as Http Status 500. So, my advice would be to define a generic error code and redirect or forward the user to a error page and display a generic message like "There is an internal server error. Contact admin blah blah ". It is not advisable to include technical details or the stacktraces in the Error page. So you can have a single Error page for all the server errors like yours

Comment: Spring Security - As the name says, it does and let it only do the security. All the Authentication related exceptions like 401 (Unauthorized), 403 (Forbidden) etc will be done by Spring Security. Rest, do not rely on Spring Security for redirection. Use Spring MVC for doing the Page forwards and redirection on errors

Comment: "Rest, do not rely on Spring Security for redirection". Yes, I understand your point. I am giving username and password and click on submit.  Spring security establishes the JDBC connection and returns AuthenticationServiceException saying "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" and redirects it to the page mentioned in authentication-failure-url.  At the same time, for other server error exception, how can we make spring to direct it error page via MVC?  How can we make spring security to handle both server exception and authentication excecption at the same time?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not getting the point.  We have authentication-failure-url attribute for spring security to redirect if authentication failure due to invalid username and password.  At the same time, by which attribute, we can make a MVC call for Server database errors?

Comment: We cannot use authentication-failure-url and MVC call both at the same time. Is that your advise?