# How to add details about cause why user is not authenticated?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, error-handling, spring-security

We added property `isBlocked` for users.

When following property is set user cannot login on our site.

We want to render error message `"your account is temporary blocked..."`

But I have not ideas how to pass this message to loginFailed controller method.

I have following spring-security configuration:

```
public class XXXSecurityServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private TerminalAdminDao terminalAdminDao;

    @Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String adminName) throws UsernameNotFoundException,
        DataAccessException {
    TerminalAdmin admin = terminalAdminDao.findAdminByEmail(adminName);
    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    if (admin != null) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        for (AdminRole adminRole : admin.getAdminRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(adminRole.getRole()));
        }
        userDetails = new User(admin.getEmail(), admin.getPassword(), true, true, true, !admin.isBlocked(),
                authorities);
    }
    return userDetails;
}
```

admin failed controlled method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginAdminFailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginError(HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("login_error", "true");
    return "admin/login";
}
```

How to understand in controller that user is blocked?

Comment: Generally additional messages are a bad idea from a security perspective. If a hacker gets that message it knows the username worked (probably also the password because a mismatch uses a different message).

Comment: Next to that you are doing it in the wrong place it isn't the task of the service to do that. The `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` already does that and if you simply set the `accountNonLocked` property instead of inventing your own. That way you get a `LockedException` for which you can add a custom message.

Comment: @M. Deinum In current realization password doesn't check - only login. Hacker can understand only that following user Name exists

Comment: Still an additional message that gives information to hackers.

Comment: @M. Deinum can you provide more details?

Comment: example http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/

Comment: @Anudeep Gade I have read it. But looks like I should rewrite current security. I believe that it can be make simpler

Comment: @M. Deinum please review this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32442820/2674303

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to register custom authentication provider and custom authentication failure handler to handle authentication exceptions.

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731144/spring-security-authenticate-exceptions-handling) question.

Comment: How to pass data from handler to controller method?

Comment: why do you need to go to controller, security is above controller, the login  failure handler or auth provider can directly handle the exception and redirect the respone to a view or directly write error in response stream.

Answer (score 0):

This works

added to controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginAdminFailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginError(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        session.setAttribute("message", getErrorMessage(request, "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"));
        return "admin/login";
    }
    // customize the error message
    private String getErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(key);
        String error = "";
        if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            error = messageSource.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", null, LOCALE_RU);
        } else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
            error = messageSource.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.accountIsLocked", null, LOCALE_RU);
        } else {
            error = messageSource.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", null, LOCALE_RU);
        }

        return error;
    }
```

But this looks ugly

Comment: Why? See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#localization

Comment: @M. Deinum Do you want to say that I should not use custom message source and should use message which uses inside spring security?   I understand how to configure this source but I cannot understand how can I get this message and pass it ti the jsp.

Comment: You don't need to Spring will handle that for you. The `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.accountIsLocked` is used as a message code to lookup the actual message. Just put something like `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.accountIsLocked=User locked` in your messages properties file and it will be automatically used, you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @M. Deinum please clarify what does it mean **will be automatically used** ? where?

Comment: Spring takes care of that. It converts codes to messages if a `MessageSource` is configured. Please read the link provided in the initial comment. Basically you are making it way to complex.

Comment: @M. Deinum I have really read localization part. But I have old question.  This message will be inside spring internals. How can I render it on jsp? which key should I use?

Comment: If you use the default login page that is already done for you. Else simply do `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}` in your JSP.

Comment: @M. Deinum  Thanks I understood .