# Spring Security - Custom login error messages

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have 2 different types of login errors:

- Incorrect user/pw
- IP blocked for too many attempts

Right now Spring is forwarding the user to `www.site.com/login?error` in both cases. How can I customize login behavior so that it forwards the user to error1 or error2 depending on the case? This forward behavior doesn't seem to be explicitly declared anywhere and I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your custom AuthenticationFailureHandler, see :
[Spring security authenticate exceptions handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731144/spring-security-authenticate-exceptions-handling)

If you just want to redirect the user to error1 or error2, your implementation can be just a simple redirect method :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

 @Override
 public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
   super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
   if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UsernameNotFoundException.class)) {
     response.sendRedirect("error1")
   } else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(LockedException.class)) {
     response.sendRedirect("error2")
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: How do I configure Spring to use that class? I tried annotating it with @Component and I also tried adding XML configuration to pom.xml (like in your link). It's complaining that `authentication-failure-handler-ref is not allowed here`.

Comment: @Atte you need to configure it in application-security.xml not in pom.xml. pom.xml is for adding dependencies, plug-ins and profiles mainly.

Comment: Ok, I tried setting up application-security.xml file according to some examples I found, but I still can't get this to work. It looks like there is no documentation on that file is supposed to be defined?

Comment: @Atte In order to get this working, you will need to add it to failureHandler in configure(final HttpSecurity http) method inside WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. http.formLogin().failureHandler(CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler)