# Spring MVC get authentication error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

How can I get user authentication error (bad username/password, disabled/locked/expired account) in @Controller and add this error to model attributes to show in Thymeleaf template? I handle it in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
http    
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .failureUrl("/login/error")
```

and process in @Controller method

```
@RequestMapping("/login/error")
public String loginError(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
    return "login";
}
```

but what method parameter I should use to do this? It's possible with HttpSession (it contains authentication exception object), but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: look into this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731144/spring-security-authenticate-exceptions-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the authentication error message with the following Thymeleaf code:

```html
<p data-th-if="${loginError == true && session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}"
   data-th-text="${session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}">
  Bad credentials.
</p>
```

No additional code in controller needed.

Answer (score -1):

You may use ModelAndView calss and addObject() method like below

```
@RequestMapping("/login/error")
public ModelAndView loginError(Model model) {   
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");  
model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
mav.addObject("errorString","User name or password is wrong")    
return mav;
}
```

In Jsp you can code like this
     Error: ${errorString}

Comment: but question is: how to get error in this method? What kind of error?

Comment: its entirely depends on the authentication mechanism that you selected for. Is it going to be LDAP or database or file based?

Comment: @VadymBorys, what kind of authentication you are using? I hope your authentication will happen in service layer and are you returning the status as string or object?