# Displaying custom error messages in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I started to learn Spring 1 month ago and I'm doing some exercises with Spring Security. When a user logins into my app, the app check if the credentials are bad or less and if the account registered in my account is enabled; so every exception has its custom message. My problem is that the custom error message doesn't display but displays only the default message. I don't know where the problem is. This is the code:

CustomAuthenticationFailure:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailure extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

        setDefaultFailureUrl("/login.html?error=true");
        
         super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
         
         String errorMessage = "Bad Credentials";
         
         if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(DisabledException.class)) {
             errorMessage = "User disabled";
         } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User account has expired")) {
             errorMessage = "Account expired";
         }
         
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, errorMessage);
    }

}
```

SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup/confirm-account").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login**").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
                
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
          crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header clearfix">
        <h1>CasaAgencyLogin!</h1>
    </div>

    <h2>Accedi</h2>

    <div th:if="${param.error != null}" 
        th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}" class="alert alert-danger">
    </div>
    
    <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
        Hai effettuato il logout. A presto!
    </div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group"><label> Username: <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"/> </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"/> </label>
        </div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Entra" class="btn btn-primary"/></div>
    </form>
    <footer class="login-footer">Non hai ancora un account? <a th:href="@{/signup}">Registrati!</a></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the keys and their values in default “messages.properties” inside “spring-security-core.jar“.

For doing this, just write a properties file (say abcxyz.properties) for all/required keys and add a bean in your bean configuration file.

```
  <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
        <value>abcxyz</value>
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you be more detailed?

Comment: You should find your spring default class which <KEY, MESSAGE> are stored. Have your abcxyz file with the same KEYs and localized MESSAGEs.
In your example, you have just updated the Java code and not the message bundle that spring security uses.
So you have to update your application context with the bean, overriding the  use of default messages.

There is another way if you want to implement the auth interface in your own way and handle the exceptions shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731144/spring-security-authenticate-exceptions-handling)

Comment: I'll do as you said but nothing, this is the code  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548054/cannot-display-custom-message-of-sessionspring-security-last-exception